# Django : How to give parameters to {% url %} tag in javascript function which will be used in FOR loop?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I try to make a button with a javascript "location.href" property in Django ListView templates.

```
{% for item in object_list %} 
   <div class="clear_float"> 
    <h2><a href = "{% url 'photo:album_detail' item.id %}">{{ item.title }}</a></h2>
    &emsp;<b><i>{{ item.description }}</i></b> 
    <p style="display:inline" class="editbutton">
    <b><button onclick="photoAdd()">Add Photo</button></b>
    {% if item.author == request.user %}
    <b><button onclick="albumEdit()">Edit</button></b>
    <b><button onclick="albumDelete()">Delete</button></b>
    {% endif %}
    </p>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

And albumEdit() and albumDelete() is coded like below.

```
function albumEdit(){
    location.href="{% url 'photo:album_edit' object.id %}";
}
function albumDelete(){
    location.href="{% url 'photo:album_delete' object.id %}";
}
```

`{% url 'photo:album_edit' object.id %}` returns "photo/object.id/edit/"

The problem is, I guess, the ListView returns object_list so the javascript function is used in FOR loop with item object.
I tried replacing object.id with item.id but it didn't work.

So I also tried another way to give a argument to javascript function like below.

```
<b><button onclick="albumEdit({% url 'photo:album_update' item.id %})">Edit</button></b>
```

and javascript

```
function albumEdit(arg){
    var address = arg;
    location.href=encodeURI(address);
}
```

Cuz I don't know much about javascript, it also didn't work.
I will be grateful for any advice and help.

Thank you :D

Comment: I fixed it with input javascript code to the onclick attribute like `<b><button onclick="location.href='{% url 'photo:album_edit' item.id %}'">Edit(</button></b>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it with input javascript code to the onclick attribute like

`<b><button onclick="location.href='{% url 'photo:album_edit' item.id %}'">Edit</button></b>`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a parameter in your js onclick function:

```
<button onclick="albumEdit({{ url 'photo:album_edit' item.id }})">Edit</button>
```

and use it to make the redirection:

```
function albumEdit(href_url){
    location.href=href_url;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment :) I tried your way but `photo:album_edit ` requires an argument 'id' so it returned "NoReverseMatch Error with no arguments not found". Also, the url format is **/photo/id/edit**, so photo/edit/id/ couldn't be matched.

Comment: Edited to make it closer to your requirements, but I think it's similiar to one of the options you've pointed.

Comment: Thank your for your time! I'm afraid your way didn't work for me but it helped me and now I fixed my problem.

Comment: Yes, it seems a more optimized solution!

Comment: And you can make your comment as an answer and mark it as the good answer to your question.

Comment: Oh I didn't know about it. Thank you :D